# How to upgrade kernel version in the netboot installer?

Tags: 16.04, uefi, pxe, debian-installer

When installing Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS over PXE in UEFI mode it fails detecting the network. On the same computer a HP EliteBook 850 G5 the installation works fine in bios mode. Even if I manually load the e1000e module the network doesn’t work. When installing Ubuntu 18.04 or Debian 9.7 I don’t have this issue. So I tried updating the kernel for from the netbook image. Unfortunately there is only little documentation or how-to's and most are outdated.
After creating a netbook image with kernel version 4.15.0-29 network was working. But debian installer did not find the required packages for the new kernel version.
The error massage was: `anna no package matching running kernel 4.15.0-29-generic`

I made sure that the new kernel was available in the local xenial main repository but it seems a special udep package is required.
So what packages are required and how can I create them?
Or is there a other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The requered udep was createt by the debian-installer build process and strored in the apt.udeb/cache/archives folder.